# Buscar valor de uma condição nas linhas e separar em um novo dataset

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, pandas, ciência-de-dados

Tenho o seguinte dataset

[image: Dataset_base]

Estou tentando criar um dataset, baseado no dataset acima.

Estou tentando buscar linha por linha os valores que não são NaN, exportar para um novo dataset esse valor vinculado a coluna 'CO_OCDE'

Ex. No index 0 - O único valor `notnull()` é o 2.5
Então no novo dataset que eu quero obter é:

[image: Dataset_resultado]

Mas encontrei outro "problema" em algumas linhas existem valores duplicados e preciso remove-los também para chegar no resultado acima.

**O que eu tentei**

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337477/select-non-null-rows-from-a-specific-column-in-a-dataframe-and-take-a-sub-select

`ex4_desc_y.loc[ex4_desc_y['NU_INTEGRALIZACAO_VESPERTINO', 'NU_INTEGRALIZACAO_NOTURNO', 'NU_INTEGRALIZACAO_INTEGRAL', 'NU_INTEGRALIZACAO_MATUTINO', 'NU_INTEGRALIZACAO_EAD'].notnull()]`

Comment: E caso vc tenha dois valores diferentes em uma linha? O que fazer?

Comment: Eu verifiquei, todos os valores que se repetem são iguais, desculpa não ter colocado essa informação acima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que a condição descrita abaixo é verdade:

1. Para cada linha, as colunas possuem ou o mesmo valor ou NaN

Sendo assim, basta fazer a média deles, pois o método `mean` ignora o NaN

Exemplo

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [10, 20, 30], "col2": [None,20,30], "col3": [None,None,30]})

>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0    10   NaN   NaN
1    20  20.0   NaN
2    30  30.0  30.0

>>> df['media'] = df.mean(axis=1)

>>> df
   col1  col2  col3  media
0    10   NaN   NaN   10.0
1    20  20.0   NaN   20.0
2    30  30.0  30.0   30.0
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Mas onde na pergunta o A.P. está usando a função "mean" ?

Comment: @jsbueno, bom dia! Pelo que entendi, creio que como os valores das linhas são iguais, basta ele fazer a média para descobrir o valor faltante na linha desejada. Abraço!

Comment: ok - como quando tem mais valores, eles aparentemente são iguais nesse caso específico, o "mean" é um hack que pode funcionar.

Comment: @jsbueno, sim parece um 'hack', eu não confio muito em solução assim pois em algum momento podem aparecer valores diferentes.... Mas parece que o autor da pergunta disse que verificou os dados e eles são iguais.

Comment: Bom dia, muito obrigado pela resposta!
Nesse caso os valores não vão ser diferentes, pois os valores se referem a duração de um curso, os códigos do curso se separam entre diurno e noturno. Então para esse caso não terá esse problema.
Mas eu estava tentando adotar uma solução mais complicada, essa solução foi sensacional! Muito obrigado

Comment: @jsbueno , eu havia perguntado antes de dar minha resposta (vide comentários da pergunta) o que fazer caso os números fossem diferentes. Fui informado que não haveria este caso.